# How to install a package via `apt-get` without flagging it as manually installed

Tags: apt

I want to install some package (`apt-get install XXX`) but I don't want that it will be added to the list of manually installed packages (`apt-mark showmanual`). How?

In Gentoo, the corresponding flag for `emerge` is `--oneshot`, which says to not add it to the world file (which corresponds to the list of manually installed packages).

---

One use case is that I want to write some scripts which would automatically install or reinstall some packages via `apt-get install` in order to fix up some messed up system, but I do not want to mark those packages as manually installed.

I imagine there are other use cases as well. As `emerge` also has such flag, I wondered if there is a similar flag for `apt-get install`.

Maybe the answer is simply *no*, and I have to manually mark it as auto (`apt-mark auto XXX`) afterwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add it to the list of automatically installed packages once again.

```
sudo apt install package
sudo apt-mark auto package
```

Comment: This is good, but will not allow user to determine which package were installed on top of initially installed system. So it will not allow tools like mine https://github.com/N0rbert/srslsud to operate in save-restore manner.

Comment: @N0rbert Is there an alternative?

Comment: For me it sounds like XY-problem. There are no alternatives, the question is questionable as for me. Command reference is at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_package_management_operations_with_the_commandline .

Comment: @N0rbert May not be an XY problem. I can give an similar example from my use case. Sometimes I install a lot of dependencies to compile software. I may not need those dependencies afterwards, and sometimes, it is a hassle to remove them one by one.

Comment: Good point, I agree about `*-dev` packages.

Comment: @N0rbert Also, e.g on Gentoo, `emerge` has the `--oneshot` flag for this purpose.

Comment: @N0rbert Another example for why you would want to do this (based on personal experience): Package A is a weak dependency of package B (`Recommends` or more likely `Suggests` in Debian packaging parlance) that was not installed at the time package B was installed, and you want to add package A but want it to be properly handled as a dependency of package B (for example, if you manually remove package B, package A should be removed).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn ok, I know about this problem. So really, not an XY-problem.

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get install --mark-auto`

> After successful installation, mark all freshly installed packages as automatically installed, which will cause each of the packages to be removed when no more manually installed packages depend on this package. This is equally to running apt-mark auto for all installed packages. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Mark-Auto.

Comment: You seem to be quoting something. Where is the quoted paragraph from?